# sending two objects of a different class to jsp and displaying information

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm learning how to use jdbc with jsp and i've encountered a problem that I've been trying to figure out to no avail and was hoping someone could provide some insight. my problem is the starlist object ends up being empty for some reason while the genrelist is fine. I am able to see based on the user input the type of movies from the selected genre but the associated stars for each movie do not show. I suspect it may be because of my function to search for stars from the List. I would try to debug and find the error but the means by which I established tomcat and eclipse and my lack of knowledge with this type of programming make it very difficult. Any help is appreciated thank you. [output of jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqxYN.jpg)

`

```
public class GenreServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    String query;
       List<Genre> genreList;
       List<Movie> genreSelect;
       List<Star> starSelect;

    @Override
       public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
       {
          query = null;

          genreList = null;
          genreSelect = null;

          ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();  
          context.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/genrelist.jsp");



       }

       @Override
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
       throws ServletException, IOException 
       { 

           query = req.getParameter("query");


        if(query == null)
        {
            try
            {
                genreList = new GenreDAO().genreList();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           req.getSession().setAttribute("genres", genreList);        
           req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/genrelist.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else
        {

            try
           {
             genreSelect = new MovieDAO().findMoviesFromGenre(query);
             starSelect = new StarDAO().findStarsFromMovies(genreSelect);
           }
            catch(Exception e)
           {
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }

               req.getSession().setAttribute("movies", genreSelect);        
               req.getSession().setAttribute("starlist", starSelect);
               req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/movielist.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        }


       }



}
```

`

```
public class StarDAO
{
    public List<Star> findStarsFromMovies(List<Movie> movieList) throws Exception
    {
        List<Star> result = new ArrayList<Star>();

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "moviedb";
        String user = "andrew"; 
        String password = "bg79jd7c";
        String sql = "select * from stars where id in (select star_id from stars_in_movies where"
                    + " movie_id in (select id from movies where title = ?));";

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;     

        for(Movie movie: movieList)
        {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user, password);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, movie.getTitle());

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                Star star = new Star();
                star.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                star.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                star.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                star.setDOB(resultSet.getString("dob"));
                star.setPhoto(resultSet.getString("photo_url"));
                result.add(star);

            }


        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        }


        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

'

```
 public class MovieListServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        List<Movie> movieItems;
        List<Star> starList;
        String query;
        Movie movie;

        @Override
           public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
           {
            query = null;
            movie = null;

              ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();  
              context.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/movielist.jsp");



           }

           @Override
           protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
           throws ServletException, IOException 
           { 




                   try
                   {
               movieItems = (List<Movie>) req.getAttribute("movies");
               req.getSession().setAttribute("movies", movieItems);       
               starList = (List<Star>) req.getAttribute("starlist");
               req.getSession().setAttribute("stars", starList);
               req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/movielist.jsp").forward(req, resp);
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }


            /**   
            try
            {
                movieItems = new MovieDAO().movieList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               req.getSession().setAttribute("movies", movieItems);       
               req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/movielist.jsp").forward(req, resp);
               */
           }



    }
```

'

'

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<table>
 <a href="home">Home</a>

 <c:forEach var="star" items="${stars}">
    <tr>

      <td>${star.id}</td>        
      <td>${star.first_name}</td>        
      <td>${star.last_name}</td>
       <td>${star.dob}</td>
        <td>${star.photo_url}</td>


    </tr>
  </c:forEach>

  <c:forEach var="movie" items="${movies}">
    <tr>

      <td>${movie.id}</td>
      <td><a href="movies?query=${movie.id}"> ${movie.title}</td>
      <td>${movie.year}</td>
      <td>${movie.director}</td>
    <td>  <img src ="${movie.banner}"></td>
      <td><a href="${movie.trailer}">trailer</a></td>         

    </tr>
  </c:forEach>

</table>
```

'

Comment: You should normally have only one servlet per application. This will make things much easier.

Comment: I only separated it so things wouldn't get messy and difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I decided to approach from another direction and create a class that incorporates both private fields of the previous classes. By having a single class  I can make a single SQL query instead of two separate ones. It doesn't solve my previous problem but it works.